# Add new dataframes(with different number of rows) generated from a loop side by side without losing any data

Tags: pandas, dataframe, join, concatenation, dtw

Here is my data -
[image]

Here is my code -

```
new=[]
for i in range(1,len(dfnew.columns)-1, 1):
    x = np.array(df.iloc[:, i].fillna(0))
    y = np.array(df.iloc[:, i+1].fillna(0))
    distance,path = fastdtw(x, y, dist = euclidean)
    for j in range(0,len(path)):
        new.append([dfnew['Time'].iloc[path[j][0]],dfnew.iloc[:,i].iloc[path[j][0]], dfnew.iloc[:,i+1].iloc[path[j][1]]])
        df_sync = pd.DataFrame(data=new,columns=["Time"+ str(i),"Jolt"+ str(i), "Jolt"+str(i+1)]).dropna()
    
        #df_sync = pd.concat([new, df_sync], axis=1)
    print(df_sync)
```

I am iterating over the main dataframe and finding a Euclidean path between Jolt 1 and Jolt 2 (which gives path as a list) over time and create a dataframe with Time, Jolt 1, and Jolt 2 as columns. In the next iteration of the main dataframe, I am finding a path between Jolt 2 and Jolt 3 and creating a dataframe with Time, Jolt 2 and Jolt 3 as my columns.

I finally want these to dataframes to be joined side by side without loosing any information. Any help would by greatly appreciated.

My output looks like this -
[image]

Comment: have you looked into `pd.concat`?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: if you don't provide a [mre] people won't help you as easily. As per the concat, it's usually a matter of your indexes. Maybe a `ignore_index = True` helps